# How to solve $\sin^3 x=\sin x\,$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$\sin^3 x=\sin x$

I have absolutely no idea what to do. I've tried graphing, and I have a little better of an understanding, but I am at a loss.

Comment: It's almost identical to your previous question.  Did you solve that yet?

Comment: I'm going to second David here. You're previous question is basically the same as this one. If you can solve that you should have no problem solving this.

Answer (score 2):

Subtract $\sin x$ from both sides:

$$\sin^3x-\sin x = 0 \quad\Longrightarrow \quad\sin x(\sin^2x - 1) = 0$$

From here, follow the steps outlined in your previous post.

Comment: Ok, I got x=0, pi/2, -pi/2. Doesn't that mean that my solution for all values would be pi/2 +/- 2(pi)k>

Comment: Or better yet $\pi/2+k\pi$.

Comment: I'm confused about the use of k(pi) and 2(pi)k. When should I use which?

Comment: Well you were right initially. It should be $\pi/2+2k\pi$ but you also have the other solution: $-\pi/2$. You would also have $-\pi/2+2k\pi$. But if you put these two solutions together, it's the same as $\pi/2+k\pi$.

Comment: Should I include the zero in my answer? Like 0+/- 2(pi)k or 0+/- (pi)k as well as what I have above?

Comment: Just write it as $k\pi$. Omit the $0$. It's redundant

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

if $\sin (x)=0$ then the statement is true.

Assume $\sin (x) \neq 0$.

We want to find $x$ such that $\sin ^3x = \sin x$. Divide by $\sin x$ to get

$\sin^2 x=1$, which implies either $\sin (x)=1$ or $\sin (x)=-1$. for what values of $x$ does this happen?